# Maven workspace resolution horked

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I'm using m2eclipse to manage maven projects. Somehow I did a bad thing, and now the system is behaving as if workspace resolution is disabled.

I have several projects that depend on a main project. This project has a version of 4.0-SNAPSHOT, and all the dependent projects reference it in the dependencies section of their poms. Everything was working fine until I created an entirely new project and mistakenly copied the pom from the main project into the new project. Suddenly, all of the dependent projects got the error:

"The container 'Maven Dependencies" references non existing library C:\users\myusername.m2\com\mydomain\myproject\4.0-SNAPSHOT\myproject-4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

I zapped the offending new project, but the error remains for all the dependent projects.

I've made no changes (to my knowledge) in the main project or any of the dependent projects, so I'm guessing something got changed in the Eclipse environment. Does m2eclipse or Maven itself maintain settings anywhere that I can blow away?

Comment: Are you using workspace dependencies resolution? Maybe you do and the dependent projects are still confused. Try to Update the project configuration (in the Maven context menu). If it doesn't help, try to re-import the projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never mind. The answer is to right-click on a project and pick Maven/Update Snapshots.