# What are the pre-requisites for using "Enable Workspace Resolution" in a Kotlin/Tomcat/Eclipse/Maven project?

Tags: kotlin, m2e-wtp

*UPDATE*

I edited the question after doing additional troubleshooting and realizing that the issue is specific to Kotlin and not a general problem with Eclipse.

*ORIGINAL QUESTION*

In an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968100/eclipse-maven-tomcat-context-initialization-failed-and-noclassdeferror-with-ko/57977553#57977553), I found that I need to set the *Disable Workspace Resolution* setting in order to successfully deploy applications to Tomcat within Eclipse, when the application has references to co-developed dependencies (i.e. dependencies which I am also primarily developing along with the main application). The *Disable Workspace Resolution* setting has many inconveniences, not the least of which is a need to run `mvn install` any time the code in a dependency project is modified.

My question now is:

**What do I need to configure, either in Eclipse, Maven, or Tomcat, in order to start using *Enable Workspace Resolution* successfully *with Kotlin*?**

I have reviewed essentially all of the SO questions on the topic, unfortunately none of them specifically address Eclipse with Kotlin:

- [Eclipse maven-enabled web app references workspace projects, but those are not deployed when running Tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750774/eclipse-maven-enabled-web-app-references-workspace-projects-but-those-are-not-d)
- [How to get Maven plugin to use Eclipse workspace resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571442/how-to-get-maven-plugin-to-use-eclipse-workspace-resolution)
- [Maven workspace resolution horked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918037/maven-workspace-resolution-horked)
- [maven-assembly-plugin and eclipse Workspace resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992264/maven-assembly-plugin-and-eclipse-workspace-resolution)
- [How make Eclipse uses maven projects even if Workspace resolution is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105371/how-make-eclipse-uses-maven-projects-even-if-workspace-resolution-is-not-working)
- [maven eclipse workspace resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535799/maven-eclipse-workspace-resolution)
- [Maven workspace resolution missing jars for local Tomcat testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683051/maven-workspace-resolution-missing-jars-for-local-tomcat-testing)
- [Maven project and Eclipse workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852989/maven-project-and-eclipse-workspace)
- [M2E Eclipse Maven Workspace resolution and CDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035751/m2e-eclipse-maven-workspace-resolution-and-cdi)
- [Eclipse Maven Workspace Resolution not seeing Generated Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822530/eclipse-maven-workspace-resolution-not-seeing-generated-classes)
- [Using Tomcat within Eclipse for a Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870217/using-tomcat-within-eclipse-for-a-maven-project)
- [Deploy Maven Project using Eclipse and Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845467/deploy-maven-project-using-eclipse-and-tomcat)
- [maven + eclipse + tomcat : class not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222978/maven-eclipse-tomcat-class-not-found-exception)
- [How to run a Maven Project In Tomcat From Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921380/how-to-run-a-maven-project-in-tomcat-from-eclipse)
- [Deployment to tomcat from eclipse via M2eclipse and Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053793/deployment-to-tomcat-from-eclipse-via-m2eclipse-and-maven)

Comment: Best of luck. Getting away from this problem is one of the primary benefits of modern launchers like Spring Boot and Micronaut.

Answer (score 0):

Go through following steps,

- Enable Workspace Resolution for your project.
- Right-click the project, then Maven > Enable Workspace Resolution.

Finally, if your project no longer resolved,

- Right-click the project, then Maven > Update Project

This should resolve your problem. If after this, your dependencies are still referenced from the file system, test the **groupId**, **artifactId** and particularly model of each dependency again.

And check if you don't have any errors in your project

- try to run Maven install.

Comment: These steps don't work (I get ClassNotFoundException). So I decided to award the bounty but keep the question open.